# Redhat | error in mod_swgi installation

Tags: redhat, mod-wsgi

I'm getting the following error when I try to install mod_wsgi

```
./configure 

checking for apxs2... no
checking for apxs... /usr/sbin/apxs
checking Apache version... 2.2.3
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile

make

/usr/sbin/apxs -c -I/usr/local/include/python2.6 -DNDEBUG   mod_wsgi.c -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib/python2.6/config  -lpython2.6 -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm
/apr-1/build/libtool --silent --mode=compile gcc -prefer-pic -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m32 -march=i386 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fno-strict-aliasing  -DLINUX=2 -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -pthread -I/usr/include/httpd  -I/usr/include/apr-1   -I/usr/include/apr-1  -I/usr/local/include/python2.6 -DNDEBUG  -c -o mod_wsgi.lo mod_wsgi.c && touch mod_wsgi.slo
sh: /apr-1/build/libtool: No such file or directory
apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=8323072
.
make: *** [mod_wsgi.la] Error 1
```

mod_wsgi 3.2
Apache 2.2
Python 2.6
apr-1.2.7-11

Is this error because of a missing package.. or else how do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a libtool package installed?

```
rpm -qa libtool*
```

By the way: Instead of compiling yourself, consider using a relevant package from the 
[IUS Community Project](http://iuscommunity.org/) repository.

Comment: libtool is already here in the system..libtool-1.5.22-7